# Problema al agregar items personalizados en un JComboBox

Tags: java

Tengo una lista que estoy obteniendo de la base de datos, y en el JComboBox deseo que aparezca el nombre pero cuando seleccione un item deseo poder obtener su ID, para ello tengo esta clase:

ItemEspecialidad.java:

```
public class ItemEspecialidades {

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Variables">

    private int codigoEspecialidad;
    private String especialidadNombre;
    private int especialidadEstado;

    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Constructor">

    public ItemEspecialidades(int codigoEspecialidad, String especialidadNombre, int especialidadEstado) {
        this.codigoEspecialidad = codigoEspecialidad;
        this.especialidadNombre = especialidadNombre;
        this.especialidadEstado = especialidadEstado;
    }

    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Getters">

    public int getCodigoEspecialidad() {
        return codigoEspecialidad;
    }

    public String getEspecialidadNombre() {
        return especialidadNombre;
    }

    public int getEspecialidadEstado() {
        return especialidadEstado;
    }

    // </editor-fold>

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getEspecialidadNombre();
    }
}
```

Esta clase contiene los atributos de cada item del JComboBox.

```
@Override
public void especialidadesEnFormatoComboBoxObtenidas(final List<Especialidad> especialidades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < especialidades.size(); i++) {
        final Especialidad especialidad = especialidades.get(i);
        final int codigo_especialidad = especialidad.getCodigoEspecialidad();
        final String especialidad_nombre = especialidad.getEspecialidadNombre();
        final int especialidad_estado = especialidad.getEspecialidadEstado();
        JCMBXEspecialidades.addItem(new ItemEspecialidades(codigo_especialidad, especialidad_nombre, especialidad_estado));
    }
}
```

Y con este metodo trato de cargar los items al JComboBox, pero me marca error en la linea: `JCMBXEspecialidades.addItem(new ItemEspecialidades(codigo_especialidad, especialidad_nombre, especialidad_estado))`, el error dice; `incompatible types: ItemEspecialidades cannot be convert to String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la declaración de tu JComboBox tiene que ser del tipo `ItemEspecialidades`